# Email a PDF page to User who clicks

Tags: apex, email, pdf, pagereference, blob.topdf

I have a custom button on Custom object Incident. When it is clicked from a particular Incident record a VF page is displayed in PDF format. I need not to show this PDF to the User instead the PDF should be mailed to that User's email Id. Please find my page and class here. Can someone help me to do the needful changes please?

Apex page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Incident_abv__c" extensions="IncidentDetailExtnController2" renderAs="pdf" >

<c:dynapdfcomponent type="header" > 
  <div>Incident Details for DMs/RMs</div>
</c:dynapdfcomponent>
  <c:dynapdfcomponent type="footer">
<div style="float:right; position:absolute;">
  <h4> Page <span class="pagenumber"/> of <span class="pagecount"/>   </h4></div>

</c:dynapdfcomponent>



   <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Detail">
       <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false">

            <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident_abv__c.Name}"/>
            <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident_abv__c.Rep_abv__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident_abv__c.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident_abv__c.Status_abv__c}"/>
            <apex:outputField style="margin-left:-10px;width:200px;" value="{!Incident_abv__c.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}"/>    
            <apex:commandLink action="{!send}" value="Send Email attached" />                                            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
    <apex:pageBlock title="Incident Transactions">
        <!--<apex:tabPanel switchType="client">-->

            <!--<apex:tab label="HCP Calls">
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
            <!--<a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_blank">Tutorials Point</a>
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>--!-->


           <!-- <apex:tab label="Samples">
            <a href="http://www.tutorialspoint.com" target="_self">Tutorials Point</a>
            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Speaker Program Attendees">

            </apex:tab>
            <apex:tab label="Synch Rate">

            </apex:tab>                               
        </apex:tabPanel>-->

       <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPDetail.size>0, true, false)}">

       <apex:tabPanel >
       <apex:tab label="HCP Calls" >

        <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >

        <div class="page-break" >
    <!-- Your content -->
        </div>
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />

         <!-- Need to put Profname string here from the map -->
        <apex:column headerValue=" ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <apex:column value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <apex:column value="{!itr.Address_Line1_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Associated Prescriber" value="{!itr.Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <apex:column headerValue=" Product" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>
        <apex:column headerValue=" Activity Date" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue=" Outcome - LOV" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"/>



        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>  


        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPSamples.size>0, true, false)}">
       <br/><br/>
        <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="Samples" >
        <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCPSamples }" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Sample Type" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"  value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Product" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Quantity (for hand samples, ESR, and DTP/BRC tied to rep)" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>


        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCPSpeaker.size>0, true, false)}">
       <br/><br/>
        <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="Speaker Program Attendees" >

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="9" value="{!oIncTranListHCPSpeaker }" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c} {!itr.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c}  {!itr.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Professional Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Address_Line1_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Product" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Program Name, Date and Location" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListSynch.size>0, true, false)}">
               <br/><br/>
        <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="Synch report">

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="6" value="{!oIncTranListSynch}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Date of Previous Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Date of Last Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Days between Synchronization" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListHCI.size>0, true, false)}">
               <br/><br/>
        <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="HCI/HCO Calls" >

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListHCI}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Detail" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>


        <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF(oIncTranListPharmacy.size>0, true, false)}">
               <br/><br/>
        <apex:tabPanel >
        <apex:tab label="Pharmacy Calls" >

         <apex:pageBlockTable columns="10" value="{!oIncTranListPharmacy}" border="true" var="itr" cellPadding="4" >
         <div class="page-break" >
    <!-- Your content -->
         </div>
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="ABS on Call" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Abs_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Account Address" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Account_Location_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Name" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Attendee Role" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Attendee_Role_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Detail" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Activity Date" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Prof_First_Name_abv__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Outcome - LOV" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" value="{!itr.Outcome_abv__c}" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:tab>
        </apex:tabPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>  

</apex:page>
```

Apex class:

```
public class IncidentDetailExtnController2{
    public Incident_abv__c oInc {get;set;}
    Id recId;
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListHCPDetail {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListHCI {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListPharmacy{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListHCPSamples{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListHCPSpeaker{get;set;}
        public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListSynch{get;set;}
    public String profName{get;set;}
    public Map<id,String> MapIncTxn{get;set;}
        public Boolean k{get;set;}

        public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }

    public IncidentDetailExtnController2(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        recId =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        oInc = (Incident_abv__c) controller.getRecord();
        /*oIncTranListHCPDetail = [SELECT Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,City_abv__c,Zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,
                                Call_Detail_abv__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__c ,Address_Line2_abv__c, Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , State_abv__c,
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Type_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Activity_Type__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , id,
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Quantity_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Product_Type_vod__c , 
                                Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , RecordType.Name , Call__c , 
                                Call__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call__r.Address_vod__c, Call__r.Detailed_Products_vod__c,Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Address_Line1_abv__c
                                 FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and RecordType.Name in ('HCP Calls')];
                 */
                     oIncTranListHCPDetail = [SELECT Name, Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,City_abv__c,Zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,
                                Address_Line2_abv__c,   id,                                 
                                Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , RecordType.Name , /*Call__c , 
                                Call__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call__r.Address_vod__c, Call__r.Detailed_Products_vod__c, */
                                Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Address_Line1_abv__c
                                 FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
                                 RecordType.Name in ('HCP Calls')];

              oIncTranListHCI = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c
            ,City_abv__c ,Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where RecordType.Name in ('HIC/HCO Calls') and Incident_abv__c = :recId];
            //Type =Pharmacy
            oIncTranListPharmacy= [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Pharmacy Calls')];

            oIncTranListHCPSamples = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Samples')];

            oIncTranListHCPSpeaker = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Speaker Program Attendees')];

            oIncTranListSynch = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Synch Rate report')];



   Map<id,String> MapIncTxn= new Map<id,String>();   

   for(   Incident_Transaction_abv__c IT :oIncTranListHCPDetail )
   {
   profName=IT.Prof_First_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c;
   MapIncTxn.put(IT.id,profName);

   }
  //  PageReference p = send();                            

    }   //constr ends  
    public PageReference attest()
    {

        return null;
    }   

    public PageReference send() {
        String addresses;
        boolean mssg;
        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

        // Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID
        PageReference pdf = Page.VF_IncidentDetail_PDF3;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)recId); //
        pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

        // Take the PDF content
        try
        {
        Blob b = pdf.getContent();

        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b); 
        addresses = 'spandan@bbb.com';


       // if (account.Contacts[0].Email != null) {}
        addresses += ':' + 'anilkumar.lingaraju@abbvie.com'+':'+'tumpu1985@gmail.com' ;
        String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( subject );
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        email.setPlainTextBody( body );

        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
            }

            catch(Exception x)
            {
            //ApexPages.Message myMsg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'Email not sent');
            //ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
            }

        return null;
    }

}
```